# has class is not working in if condition

Tags: jquery, html, css

I wrote the following code for Accordion, but when I test it, `'not'` is shown twice, while `'hve'` is not shown at all.

```
$('.st-accordion li a').click(function() {

  if ($(this).parent().not('activeaccordion')) {
    $(this).parent().addClass('activeaccordion')
    alert('not');
    $(this).next().slideToggle();
  } else {
    if ($(this).parent().hasClass('activeaccordion')) {
      alert('hve');
      $(this).parent().removeClass('activeaccordion')
      $(this).next().slideToggle();
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: That's because `not` returns an object and an object is a truthy value in JavaScript. You should check the `length` of the returned collection. Also the selector `activeaccordion ` is wrong, you are missing `.` for the class selector.

Answer (score 1):

Use

`if(!$(this).parent().hasClass('activeaccordion')){`

You can also use `$(this).parent().toggleClass('activeaccordion');` to set the class if it is not set or vice versa.